# Could not add AWS codepipeline as a source for codebuild

Tags: aws

want to create codebuild project, but i neeed build source to be codepipeline, not a specific codecommit branch, so that i want to force codebuild to get the source from the codepipeline source stage in order to use one codebuild project for multiple pipelines.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has nothing to do with Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not add codepileine as a source for your build project unless you have already created the codebuild project while pipeline creation.

if u have created the build project separately, you will not be able to use codepipeline as a source stage

Answer (score 0):

Codepipeline obviously cannot be used as a source so you have to use other solution. My proposal is to store the code in S3 and use it as a source for pipelines.

You can store the code manually or trigger a notification SNS to start a workflow which copies the code automatically (when there are changes in the repository, for example).